# https in page url but not displaying in google search results

Tags: seo, google-search, https

Why a site even when crawled with https, the indexed urls are https but the search result that google does not display https appearing in result url.

**The results in red have links to https but why google is not displaying that specifically ?**

Do we have some implementation by which google starts to show that in result ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that HTTPS is working okay which it seems to be:

Make sure you redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Make sure your sitemap, if you have one, is using HTTPS.

If you have made this change in the past few months, please know that the changes will take quite a while to be relfected in the SERPs. Google keys their database off of a couple of things. One of the principle keys is the URL. This is the full URL. In otherwords, for your site, HTTPS and HTTP are two different URLs. As Google refetches your pages, with the redirect, Google will replace the HTTP URL with the HTTPS URL.

It is that simple.

Google will have to fetch each and every page in order for it to change in the SERPs. This takes time depending upon how fresh your site/pages is/are and the size of your site. Keep in mind that search engines are not real-time and that Google can fetch all the URLs within it's index within about 10 months. This means that it will take months, but not likely more than 10 months.

If you have dome everything right, then it is just a matter of time and being patient.

Comment: Thanks closetnoc. But my point is the HTTPS URLs are crawled. Even what Google has in results is HTTPS. But in displaying it URL visible in first result is HTTPS, while others shows http to user while actually the link is to HTTPS.

Comment: @abhinsit I guess I was not entirely clear in my thoughts. Sorry. It is possible that both HTTPS and HTTP exist in the index at the same time and one, being older with metrics, outperforms the newer HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTPS doesn't always show alongside links with breadcrumbs. If you search and hover your mouse over the links, you can see the destination.

For example:

[image: HTTPS Link]

You see here that the destination URL includes HTTPS, even though it doesn't show in the result itself.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but this the only question. Why does this happen

Comment: That's generally just how they display breadcrumbs. Users are generally more interested in seeing the website and path than the protocol itself (which most won't understand anyway).